# Transaction open in a specific database can to afect other database?

Tags: sql, database, transactions

Maybe, it's a stupid question, but....

If I open transaction with begin tran in a Sql Manager for example, and I forgot to do rollback or commit.. This transaction can to affect other databases... To leave slowly queries in the other database for example or anything else?

It's because I forgot an open transaction, and a stupid programmer said that my transaction had affected his database.

Obs. The databases are in same instance.

Comment: Locking issue? If you are debugging on this DB using some UI tool/software/application, the db might be locked(depends on the implimentation of the software), only after you rollback or commit the transaction, the lock will not be released.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: But the question is, begin tran in DataBaseA can be affect DatabaseB? Example: 
use DatabaseA begin tran select BancoA.dbo.TabelaA where Id = 1 
This transaction in databaseA affect databaseB?

Yes @MartinSmith, SQL Server..... sorry.